# Htaccess wild card Request Contains?

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

I am trying to write a conditional statement in `.htaccess`, what is the correct way to part match against the request?

I have this which matches a request for `/myfile.xml` but also want to match `/myfile`.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/myfile.xml'">
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have this which matches a request for `/myfile.xml` but also want to match `/myfile`

That doesn't sound like a "contains" operation, as the title suggests, since you would seem to want to match just one or the other.

For this you could just use the logical "or" operator (ie. `||`). For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/myfile.xml' || %{REQUEST_URI} == '/myfile'">
```

Matches `/myfile.xml` or `/myfile`.

Or, you could use a regular expression:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/myfile(\.xml)?$#">
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

HOWEVER, depending on what you are actually trying to do, an `<If>` expression might not be the correct tool for the job.